# how to extract a text message from an audio wav file?

Tags: java, audio, text

I'm preparing a program which hides a text file in an audio file. The encoding works fine, but not the decoding. At first, I have an in.txt (contains the text) file that a will hide it in an audio file (.wav, (16 bits 44.1kHz) to get an audioencoded file. In decoding I should have the audioencoded file to extract the message to out.txt.

My problem is, as result, I get the out.txt file, but the text isn't inside it (it has a size 1Ko like the in.txt). But when I open it I didn't see the text extracted.

This is my code:

```
public static void main (String [] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int maxChar = 40000;

    System.out.println("What would you like to do? (enter the number)");
    System.out.println("1 - Encode a text file into an audio file");
    System.out.print("2 - Decode an audio file(you will need the key) ");
    int command = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println();

    if (command == 1) {

        char [] contents = new char[maxChar]; // Initialize an array of characters to read the text file into          
        System.out.print("Enter text file name that you want to encode (must be a plain text file) : ");
        String textToEncode = scan.next(); // The text file to read in
        if (!textToEncode.endsWith(".txt")) // Check if the filename ends with .txt and add the extension if it doesn't
            textToEncode += ".txt";        

        File file = new File(textToEncode);
        try {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(file,"UTF-8");
            s.useDelimiter("\\Z");
            if(s.hasNext()) {
                contents = s.next().toCharArray();
            }
            // The \\Z delimiter in combination with .next() will read input until there isn't any left
            //System.out.println(contents);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Enter the audio file name that you want the text encoded into (must be a .wav file)");
        System.out.print("or if you want a generated clip of static, type \"1\" : ");
        double[] audioFile = getAudioFile(scan.next());

        /* DEBUG
        System.out.println("Audio File before data written");
        for (int p = 0; p < 100; p++) {
        System.out.print(audioFile[p] + " ");

        } System.out.println();
         */

        int audioCounter = 0; // an extra counter for the audio file since its values cap at 1.0 and data would be lost if we tried adding the text to those points. The extra counter allows us to skip over those points.
        for (int i = 0; i < contents.length; i++) {
            while ((audioFile[i+audioCounter] + (double)(contents[i])/10000.0) >= 1.0) {audioCounter++;} // Increments audioCounter if the encoding would make the value at that point go above 1.0
            audioFile[i+audioCounter] += ((double)(contents[i]))/10000.0;                          
        }

        System.out.println("Audio File after data written");
        for (int p = 0; p < 100; p++) {
            System.out.print(audioFile[p] + " ");

        } System.out.println();
        */

        System.out.print("Enter a name for the output audio file with the text encoded in it : ");
        String outAudio = scan.next();
        if (!outAudio.endsWith(".wav")) // Check if the filename ends with .wav and add the extension if it doesn't
            outAudio += ".wav";

        StdAudio.save(outAudio, audioFile);
        scan.close();
    }

    if (command == 2) {
        System.out.print("Enter audio file name that you want to decode (must be a wav file) : ");
        String audioToDecode = scan.next();
        //System.out.println();
        if (!audioToDecode.endsWith(".wav")) // Check if the filename ends with .wav and add the extension if it doesn't
            audioToDecode += ".wav";

        System.out.print("Enter audio file that is the decoder key (must be a wav file) : ");
        String audioKey = scan.next();
        //System.out.println();
        if (!audioKey.endsWith(".wav")) // Check if the filename ends with .wav and add the extension if it doesn't
            audioKey += ".wav";

        double[] audioEncoded = StdAudio.read(audioToDecode);
        double[] key = StdAudio.read(audioKey);
        char [] contents = new char[maxChar];

        System.out.println("\nAudio File with data encoded");
        for (int z = 0; z < 100; z++) {
            System.out.print(audioEncoded[z] + " " );
        } System.out.println();
        System.out.println("\nOriginal Audio File");
        for (int z = 0; z < 100; z++) {
            System.out.print(key[z] + " " );
        }System.out.println();
        System.out.println("\n(Encoded - Key) * 10000");
        for (int z = 0; z < 100; z++) {
            System.out.print(10000 * ( audioEncoded[z] - key[z] ) + " " );
        } System.out.println();
        */

        int contentCounter = 0; // Increments whenever a character is added to the contents array
        for (int i = 0; i < key.length; i++) {
            if (!((audioEncoded[i] - key[i] == 0))) { // If there's a value there, then put it in the char array. If not then nothing was encoded and it can be skipped.
                contents[contentCounter] = (char) (Math.round((float) (10000 * ( audioEncoded[i] - key[i] )))); // For some reason the values end up being a tiny bit off and need to be rounded to the nearest int before being converted to characters

                contentCounter++;
                // DEBUGGING    System.out.print(contents[contentCounter-1] + " " + (Math.round((float) (10000 * ( audioEncoded[i] - key[i] )))) + " " + ((10000 * ( audioEncoded[i] - key[i] ))) + "\n" ); //debug line for trying to figure out why the values were off
            }
        }

        System.out.print("Enter the name for a text file to write the data to : ");
        String outputName = scan.next();
        if (!outputName.endsWith(".txt"))
            outputName += ".txt";

        // Lots of error catching here, but in short it writes the character array "contents" to the file "outputName"
        BufferedWriter writer = null;
        try {
            writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputName));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < contentCounter+1; i++) {
                writer.write(contents[i]);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    StdAudio.close();
    System.out.println("The End.");

}

// Makes a 5 second audio clip of static. 44100 values per second.
public static double[] makeAudio () {
    double[] audio = new double[5*44100];
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < audio.length; i++)
        audio[i] = 2*Math.random() - 1; // Generates a random double between -1 and 0.999999

    return audio;
}

// Returns the audio file given the name or uses another method to generate a clip of static if the argument is 1
public static double[] getAudioFile(String input) {
    double[] audioFile;

    if (input.equals("1")) {
        audioFile = makeAudio(); // Generates a clip of static.
        System.out.print("Please enter a name for the generated audio clip : ");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name = scan.next();
        if (!name.endsWith(".wav")) // Check if the filename ends with .wav and add the extension if it doesn't
            name += ".wav";
        StdAudio.save(name, audioFile);
    }
    else {
        if (!input.endsWith(".wav")) // Check if the filename ends with .wav and add the extension if it doesn't
            input += ".wav";

        audioFile = StdAudio.read(input); // Reads in the audio as an array of doubles
    }

    return audioFile;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through with a debugger to make sure everything you expect to happen is actually happening and variable contents are what you expect them to be?

Comment: I think especially of interest is what value your `contentCounter` variable is at

Comment: all is fine,I haven't any error,on executing or debugging :(

Comment: but I still have the same problem in the out.txt,I can't see any message inside

Comment: @Sam initilally contentCounter = 0 then it will increments whenever a character is added to the contents array from the file in.txt

Comment: But what is its value after the for loop?

Comment: I think I have a problem with Audio File with data encoded,this is the result when I debug:
Audio File with data encoded
-0.5638294625690481 0.7196874904629658 -0.8515274513992737 -0.46345408490249335.....

Comment: Original Audio File
-0.5638294625690481 0.7196874904629658 -0.8515274513992737...

Comment: (Encoded - Key) * 10000
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0...

Comment: Were you able to convert the wav file to text?